# AWS lambda with SQS trigger keeps retrying and putting job back in the queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function with SQS as its trigger. when lambda executes, regardless of an error happening or not, it will put the job back in the queue and creates a loop.

1. should I return something in lambda function to let SQS know that I got the message(done the job)? how should I ack the message? as far as I know we don't have ack and nack in SQS.
2. Is there any option in the SQS configuration to only retry N time if any job fails?

Comment: It *doesn't* put messages back in the queue unless your Lambda function times out or indicates an error.

Comment: I know but I want it not to put it back into the queue even if it fails!

Comment: OK, just wanted to clarify because your original paragraph suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For standard uses cases you do not have to actively manage success-failure communication between lambda and SQS.  If the lambda returns without error within the timeout period, SQS will know the message was successfully processed.  If the function returns an error, then SQS will retry a configurable number of times and finally direct still-failing messages to a Dead Letter Queue (if configured).

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html): Amazon SQS supports dead-letter queues, which other queues (source queues) can target for messages that can't be processed (consumed) successfully.

Important:  Add your DLQ to the SQS queue, not the Lambda.  Lambda DLQs are a way to handle errors for async (event-driven) invocation.